# Should I normalize an entity to one-to-one relationship model in gae

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have a student entity which already has about 12 fields.Now, I want to add 12 more fields(all related to his academic details).Should I normalize(as one-to-one) and store it in a different entity or should I keep on adding the information in Student entity only.
I am using gaesession to store the logged in user in memory

```
session = get_current_session()
session['user'] = user
```

Will this affect in the read and write performance/cost of the app? Does cost of storing an entity in the memcache(FE instance) related to the number of attributes stored in an entity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally the costs of either writing two entities or fetching two entities will be greater than the cost of writing or fetching a single entity.

Write costs are associated with the number of indexed fields.  If you're adding indexed fields, that would increase the write cost whenever those fields are modified.  If an indexed field is not modified and the index doesn't need to be updated, you do not incur  the cost of updating that index.  You're also not charged for the size of the entity, so from a cost perspective, sticking with a single entity will be cheaper.

Performance is a bit more complicated.  Performance will be affected by 1) query overhead and 2) the size of the entities you are fetching.

If you have two entities, you're going to suffer double the query overhead, since you'll likely have to query/fetch the base student entity and then issue a second query/fetch for the second entity.  There may be certain ways around this if you are able to fetch both entities by id asynchronously.  If you need to query though, you're perf is likely going to suffer whenever you need to query for the 2nd entity.

On the flip side, perf scales negatively with entity size.  Fetching 100 1MB entities will take significantly longer than fetching 100 500 byte entities.  If your extra data is large, and you typically query for many student entities at once, then storing the extra data in a separate entity such that the basic student entity is small, you can increase performance significantly for the cases where you don't need the 2nd entity.

Overall, for performance, you should consider your data access patterns, and try to minimize extraneous data fetching for the common fetching situation.  ie if you tend to only fetch one student at a time, and you almost always need all the data for that student, then it won't affect your cost to load all the data.

However, if you generally pull lists of many students, and rarely use the full data for a single student, and the data is large, you may want to split the entities.

Also, that comment by @CarterMaslan is wrong.  You can support transactional updates.  It'll actually be more complicated to synchronize if you have parts of your data in separate entities.  In that case you'll need to make sure you have a common ancestor between the two entities to do a transactional operation.

Comment: I generally pull a list of many students and rarely use all the student data.Will projection queries help me in reducing the extra overhead?

Comment: Yes, that's a great idea.  Projection queries may cause somewhat higher write costs because all the projected attributes must be indexed.  However, if you are read heavy, the savings in read costs can more than make up for the added read expense, plus not fetching the entire entity would improve perf.

Comment: Just a small doubt.Projection queries don't need composite indexes? Am I correct?

Comment: Not sure about that one.  Check to see if there's additional entries to your index.yaml.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how often these two "sets" of data need to be retrieved from datastore. As a general principle in GAE, you should de-normalize your data, thus in your case store all properties in the same model. This, will result in more write operations when you store an entity but will reduce the get and query operations.

Memcache is not billable, thus you don't have to worry about memcache costs. Also, if you you use [ndb](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/) (and I recommend you to do so), caching in memcache is automatically handled.

Comment: so, how is write operation(cost) related to the number of attributes?
Does the above code "session['user'] = user" uses memcache or uses Frontend instance 
PS:I am already using ndb.

Comment: One gotcha on de-normalizing. GAE Datastore doesn't support transactions in a way guaranteed to avoid concurrent update collisions. So if the fields in student are often independently and concurrently updated by multiple processes, put the sets of fields that will be updated together in separate entities in 1-1 relation to student. You can still de-normalize into student the fields needed for fast retrieval, but consider update concurrency before putting everything in student.

Comment: The write operations for an entity are affected by the number of indexed properties your model has, and the composite indexes as well. Take a look at [Paid Apps: Budgeting, Billing, and Buying Resources](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/billing#cost_resource), in the section _Costs for Datastore Calls_.